# MaterializeCSS: Initializing SideNav when loading it using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, materialize

I use [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) on my portfolio website. I have stored my header + navbar in a file `header.html` and load it on every page using [jQuery load](https://api.jquery.com/load/). (I know this is bad for SEO)

**Problem:**
The sideNav doesn't open on mobile sometimes, even though I initialize it properly.

Here is my code:

header.html

```
<header class="header deep-purple center-align">
<div class="row valign-wrapper">
  <div class="col s6 right-align">
    <img class="responsive-img circle" src="/assets/media/profile.png" alt="" >
  </div>

    <div class="col s6 left-align">
      <img class="responsive-img" src="/assets/media/logo_main_light.svg" alt="">
    </div>

</div>
<h1 style="font-size: 4.2rem;">Haider Ali Punjabi</h1>

<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper deep-purple darken-2">
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="/index.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resume.html">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="/photography">Photography</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="side-nav deep-purple darken-2" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="/index.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resume.html">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="/photography">Photography</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

index.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#header").load("/header.html",function(){
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();

  });
});
```

I know I am initializing it properly, and after the navbar has been loaded, so I don't see why this doesn't work.